# Argument of type "list[str]" cannot be assigned to parameter "__value" of type "str" in function "index". How do I fix this?

Tags: python, list, random, parameters

I have been programming a type based combat game - think of it a bit like Pokemon. In order to win a round and hit the opponent, the computer roles a virtual 6 sided dice for each player and the highest roll wins.

There are different advantages you can obtain, one being a "wizard" that increases your chances on rolling a higher number.

As I'm relatively new to python, the use of "random.choices" and the weight argument was the only way I could think to achieve the higher probability rolls. However, this has led to the issue where, when I try to return the value, it produces the error that the value has to be a string or number not in a list:

```
def wizardSpeed():
    dice_num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    probability = [0.25, 0.45, 0.65, 0.85, 0.9, 0.85]
    dice_roll = random.choices(dice_num, probability)
    return dice_roll
```

I tried to fix this (with my limited knowledge :/) by obtaining the position of the value in the list, then converting the one value in that position to an integer before returning it. I then got a similar error (one in title):

```
def wizardSpeed():
    dice_num = ["1","2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
    probability = [0.25, 0.45, 0.65, 0.85, 0.9, 0.85]
    dice_roll = random.choices(dice_num, probability)
    position = dice_num.index(dice_roll)
    result = int(dice_num[position])
    return result
```

Is there a way to fix this? I am trying to take one value from the list to be used as an integer in a variable later in the program.

Comment: I'm sorry, **what exactly is going wrong**? What you posted looks like some sort of `mypy` error, not an actual Python error. Please **always describe precisely what the problem is**. If I define your original `wizardSpeed` function, and call it, it runs fine. Please always provide a [mcve]

Comment: "however, this has led to the issue where, when I try to return the value, it produces the error that the value has to be a string or number not in a list:" *what produces "the error"*? *What error*? The python runtime goes to great lengths to provide a good error message and a stack trace. Don't just *omit* that from your question. Please help us help you, don't make us *guess* what's going on. Show use *precisely*

Comment: presumably, you want to return an integer from your wizardSpeed function, however, `random.choices` returns a list, in this case a list of length 1... so you should maybe just get that element from the list? But again, **don't make us guess**. As for the error in the title, coming from something (you decided not to share what is actually providing that error with us), it is telling you that `dice_num.index(dice_roll)` won't work because `dice_roll` is a list. have you tried to see what `random.choices` is actually returning?

Comment: So you have a list of one item and you need to get the item out? That's just `dice_roll[0]`. In the future, please make a [mre], which will help catch simple mistakes like this. Or if you honestly didn't know that, please do a Python tutorial, cause we're not here to teach the language basics. Either way, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for more tips.

Comment: @juanpa "you decided not to share what is actually providing that error"* -- I think OP's just new and doesn't realize that it's not Python saying that. It's probably their IDE, like Pyright in VSCode.